# CNContactPickerViewController with UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitoolbar, cncontact

How do I implement same contact picker as in iOS Apple Maps?

As you can see from pictures, in Maps app you can switch between favourites places and your contacts. I want switching between picker and some custom table without dismissal animation and with common control like `UISegmentedControl`.

I have no problem with presenting `CNContactPickerViewController` nor with implementing `UISegmentedControl`. I have problem with adding toolbar to `CNContactPickerViewController`.

- I've tried to push it into my `UINavigationController` with no success.
- I've tried to add `UIToolbar` but `CNContactPickerViewController`
  doesn't have `UINavigationController`.
- I also tried to add it to subviews and `childViewControllers`

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/ContactsUI_Framework/index.html) doesn't say anything how to use it.
This [page](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-9-swift/9781491936689/ch04.html) claims:

> Instances of the CNContactPickerViewController cannot be pushed to the
>   stack.

Any advice is appreciated :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `CNContactPickerViewController` is highly secure and runs in a separate process. I'm trying to find documentation to support that theory, but I think that's the reason why there's no API that allow devs to augment its appearance.

The reason you're seeing it in the Apple Maps app is because ... Apple apps can use private APIs. They're doing something special for their app which they haven't made publicly available.

Comment: +1 to this. A bit more supporting evidence (though nothing conclusive): iOS doesn't require permission to display a `CNContactPickerViewController`, since the app only has access to the final selection. This means that it _can't_ allow access to its view hierarchy, or applications would be able to iterate the labels in the table view and read contact information that way.